# Delphi, PNG, AlphaSkin, ImageList, Resource

Tags: delphi, resources, load, png, alpha

I want to load AlphaSkin's Imagelist from resource.
Commonly I know, how to load a normal bitmap, and use in my application.
But there is not help, how to load a prev. stored PNG image into alphaskin imagelist.

The imagelist supports only:
Add(Bitmap...)

methods, but there is no way to load PNG image directly.

I found this function:

AddImageFromRes

But I don't know, how this working.

May you can know more about this. The general question: how to compile PNG images into the res file to I can get them into Alpha imagelist.

Thanks for your help:
   dd

---

So: the question have three parts.

I have a PNG icon library, and I want to create resources from some icons.
For example: 
The AlphaSkin Button have ImageList property, and I can set the glyph from here.
I want to make my own button, that have my own kinds, with hungarian captions, icons, and mr* kind (mrOk).
For this I need to store the icons.

1.)
How to store PNG to AlphaSkin CAN read it?
I know that RCDATA can hold ANY files, so I can compile them into res file.

2.)
How to I read this previously stored PNG resource?

3.)
I tested this AddImageFromRes function, but I got interesting bugs.
May I do something wrong, or my I need to set something I missed before.
May I need to convert PNG files to "ico"? Is this a possible solution?
Some example can help us...

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Comment: Are you asking how to *store* a PNG as a resource, or are you asking how to *load* a PNG from a resource? Those are two completely different questions.

Comment: I corrected the question.  Thanks: dd

Comment: Hi! That was an AS bug. Sorry. dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an AlphaSkin bug. Sorry.

dd